# Magento: Moving the block top.menu from the header to the content

Tags: xml, magento, content-management-system

How can I programatically move the block `top.menu` from the header to the content of the homepage in magento (or above it)

Which xml file(s) should be edited and where should move the code

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu'); ?>
```

to. I'm new to Magento so I'm not sure where to even start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I would do it:

First off, you'll want to create a local.xml file in app/design/frontend/default/YOUR THEME/layout so that you aren't affecting core files.

In the local.xml file put this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
<action method="unsetChild"><name>top.menu</name></action>  

<reference name="content">
 <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Here you are unsetting the block from the standard layout and then resetting it in the content block.  You can put all layout changes for the site in local.xml and that way they are in one place and you are editing core files - just find the block you want to adjust in the core xml files and add it to your local.xml (there's a ton of info on google about local.xml files if you want more info).

Also, you may need to comment out the line in header.phtml where it says:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu'); ?>
```

to

```
<?php // echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu'); ?>
```

Again, if you are doing this then you'll want to copy the header.phtml file from the base Magento folder into your custom theme folder so that you aren't editing core files.

I believe unsetchild should remove the block from header.phtml by default but when I just tested it the block remained so if you comment it out then it should work OK.

Comment: thank u for the explain it was quiet helpful.. but this should only take care of disabling or removing it from the layout.

what about moving the block to the content of some cms (which is actually the home page)

my solution until now was:
to remove the 
`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu'); ?>`

and put this code in the column1.phtml directly above the content:

`<?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('web/default/cms_home_page') == Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier()): ?>
                 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean..you want top.menu to only appear on the CMS home page and not on any other pages?  Can you rephrase what it is you are trying to do?